# Sending a file with jquery and xml

Tags: jquery, xml, file, servlets, upload

I made a simple script to send some user data to my servlet. The user data is taken from a form and marshalled into an xml document and then sent to the servlet, now I want to also take a file (image) and send it with the xml document, is there a way to do it without making another servlet that stores file and using another .post ?

Here is my code so far:

```html
    $.post( "../Profile", updateData,
        function( data ){
            //This is the success function
            var xmlDoc = data;
            var xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlDoc);
            console.log("log. Data: " + xmlString);
            location.reload(); //ricarica la pagina a profilo aggiornato
        }
    );
```

any suggestion about what to do are well appreciated, thanks everybody.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to send the data as json, and then parse json with another library like gson? (i think it's less bothersome)

Comment: unfortunatly my specifics are to use xml

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you encode both the image file and the xml doc as form parameters in a single multipart/form-data POST and then retrieve them both from the same servlet?

Comment: I thought about it, but I'm working on a project and I've been asked to make all the transitions client-server using xml in respect with the MVC pattern. Seems like I shouldn't be using parameters but just reading the xml in input from the request. I was thinking at this point to do another servlet just for file upload propose and spit things up with two request.